# How resource files in Windows work and why use them?

Tags: windows, resource-files

I'm getting frustrated at every tutorial/book using resource files but never explaining why they use them or how they work under the hood. I haven't been able to find any information whatsoever on this. I'm hoping someone could create a public answer for everyone to find later.

Some relevant information may include...

1. What is the rationale behind resource files?
2. Are they a feature or Windows or language compilers?
3. Why should you not just create a GUI via code only?
4. Are there situations where only a resource file can be used or only code can be used?
5. How do resource file entries get converted in to actual window's objects at runtime?
6. What exactly does the resource compiler do with the entries and what does the compiled format contain?
7. Is a difference in loading times created using resource files rather than code?
8. What's your recommendation on using resources or code?

Any additional information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally in Windows development, resource files are embedded directly in the executable binary. I don't think this particular approach to resources is much used outside Windows, but Java has a cross-platform way of doing the same thing by storing resources in a compressed archive along with the executable bits. You can see the same thing in Android development, where resources are embedded in APK files. It's pretty common (except in Windows binaries) to use XML to specify resources.

Packing resources into an executable has the potential advantage of offering a "single-file solution"; the executable contains the application logic and the supporting resources all bundled into one file. This can be helpful in some situations, but it's pretty rare to find a substantial application that can be distributed as a single file. In any event, this method of packing resources goes back to the earliest days of Windows development; Microsoft probably drew on approaches that were common in other desktop micro platforms of that time, all of which, I guess, are now long dead.

Resources allow certain things -- typically user interface elements - to be specified declaratively, rather than in code. A nice feature is to allow these declarative elements to be locale-dependent. So, for example, we can specify a main menu for English, one for French, and so on, and have the proper one picked at run-time.

It's easier to have graphical design tools write and edit declarative resource files than code, although it's not impossible to have them output code directly. In any event, it's usually considered "nicer" to have user interface elements separated from application logic. With careful design, the user interface bits and other resources can be edited after the application itself is finalized, and can be maintained separately.

Classical Windows resources are compiled by a resource compiler into a packed binary format, poked in that format into object (.obj, .o) files, and then linked into the executable by the linker. I suspect that with modern development tools, all that stuff is completely hidden, and you just see the final executable. The Windows APIs know how to unpack resources from the executable, and turn them into programmatic representations -- not code, as such, but data in memory that can be used by other API calls.

In my experience, Windows (binary) resources don't have any significant overhead over explicit coding, although processing an XML-based resource can be a bit slower.

Coding a user interface usually offers more flexibility than using resources; it's not uncommon to see both approaches used in the same application.

Comment: That makes sense. So to my understanding, if I were to write something like "101 icon.ico" in the RC file, icon.ico data would be compiled in to the binary, and when I call LoadIcon(...,101), windows would create and return an Icon object to me using that data? I assume the objects are loaded on demand and not all at once on startup. That seems quite reasonable and useful.

Comment: My recollection is that the relevant section of the executable -- the one that contains the resources -- is actually mapped into memory. So reading the resource is not a file  operation at all after the executable is loaded, but a memory operation. I believe that icons and menus have data structures in memory that map almost exactly onto the compiled resource file contents, so the data mapped into memory can be used almost exactly as it is. However, this could well vary between Windows versions.